# How to get rid of the horizontal scroll line in website

Tags: scroll, line

Im trying to get rid of the horizontal scroll line in my website can anyone help me.
website name is www.realcombatmedia.com

thanks

Comment: No problem @reggie! Make sure to accept my answer by clicking the check mark to the left. Thanks and good luck your website, your doing great so far

Answer (score 0):

The line of underscores is causing your page to extend to the right. Either shorten your underscores or place some kind of space to make it wrap.

If you want to hide what is going past the div parent of your text add this to your css.

```
div { overflow-x: hidden; }
```

Comment: No problem @reggie! Make sure to accept my answer by clicking the check mark to the left. Thanks and good luck your website, your doing great so far.

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by the line of underscores in the following text;

> THOMAS OOSTHUIZEN-MARCUS JOHNSON
>
> SHOBOX TRIPLE HEADER COMPLETE UNDERCARD
>
> ---

This line can't be wrapped, so is sticking out the right side of the page

[image]

And without the line

[image]

Comment: @reggie - if you have the chance, would you mind accepting the answer?